# How do I Correctly Load Classes From Other Files?

Tags: python

I have written a series of classes that inherit from the parent class Command.py and are in the same directory as each other. These classes have no problem loading with the following statement:

```
from Command import Command
```

The issue lies if I try to utilize these classes elsewhere back a few directories like so:

```
project
├── main.py
└── step_sequencer
    └── commands
        ├── Command.py
        ├── OtherClasses.py
        └── command_parser.py
```

Where the hang-up is happening is that I am importing a function from command parser in main.py and it seems like the scope of my functions are now at the top level so the import commands don't work:

main.py:

```
from Commands.CommandsParser import load_classes, parse

print(load_classes())
```

command_parser.py:

```
import sys
import importlib.util
import os
import sys
import inspect
abs_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)

def load_classes():
    # blank dictionary of all possible command references
    command_references = {}
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    files = os.listdir(path)
    print(path)
    path_dot = path.replace("/", ".")
    path_dot = path_dot.strip('.')

    # get list of all .py files in directory except this script
    command_filenames = [x for x in files if x.endswith('.py') and x != os.path.basename(__file__) and x !=
                         '__init__.py']
    # bring the Command.py to the front of the list to be loaded in first
    command_filenames.insert(0, command_filenames.pop(command_filenames.index('Command.py')))
    for cmd_file in command_filenames:
        # get rid of extension
        command_name = os.path.splitext(cmd_file)[0]
        
        # Original implementation
        # module = importlib.import_module('Commands.{0}'.format(command_name))
        # module = importlib.import_module(command_name)
        
        # This was my workaround here for this method
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(command_name, path + '/' + command_name + '.py')
        module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)

        # iterate over attributes of each module and add classes only
        for attribute_name in dir(module):
            attribute = getattr(module, attribute_name)
            if inspect.isclass(attribute):
                try:
                    # try to get its type, in order to add it to the dictionary for instant access
                    command_type = getattr(attribute, 'type')
                    command_references[command_type] = attribute
                except AttributeError:
                    # class has no type, ignore it, since Command class has no type.
                    pass
    return command_references
```

Command.py:

```
import sys
import pyautogui as auto


class Command:

    # list to create track of all instantiated objects
    instances = []
    instance_count = 0

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.json = json
        # append instance of class
        Command.instances.append(json['type'])
        try:
            self.name = json['name']
        except KeyError:
            # tally up count of instances of said object
            for instance in self.instances:
                if instance == json['type']:
                    self.instance_count += 1
            # name command with generic command name + instance count
            self.name = json['type'] + str(self.instance_count)

    def execute(self, commands, counter):
        pass

    def print(self):
        return self.json

    def is_valid(self):
        pass
```

ClickMouse.py (child class):

```
from Command import Command, auto
import sys


class Click(Command):
    type = "click"

    def __init__(self, json):
        super().__init__(json)
        try:
            self.button = json["button"]
        except KeyError:
            print("Backend: Error: missing 'button' parameter, set default to left click" )
            self.button = "left"

    def execute(self, commands, commands_counter):
            try:
                if self.button != 'double':
                    auto.click(button=self.button)
                else:
                    auto.doubleClick()
            except  auto.PyAutoGUIException:
                print(auto.PyAutoGUIException)
                sys.exit(1)

    def is_valid(self):
        return self.button in ['left', 'right', 'middle', 'double']

    def print(self):
        return ""
```

What is the best practice to be able to bring this step_sequencer directory anywhere and it be able to resolve the paths/importing issues?

Comment: Just a remark. all `.py` file (module) names should `snake_case` and class names `UpperCaseCamelCase`. So creating file `command.py` and `class Command` is a correct practice. https://visualgit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/naming_convention.html

Answer (score 0):

To access `Command.py` from `main.py`, use:

```
from step_sequencer.commands import Command
```

To access the `Command` class inside of `Command.py`, use:

```
from step_sequencer.commands.Command import Command
```

Comment: Your second statement is not the best way to do it.

Comment: I'm calling the load_classes function from main that searches for all of the children classes in the Commands folder. The issue i'm having is that while in the child class, an error is thrown that it cannot find the module.